# Make an exception WordDelimiterFilterFactory

Tags: solr, filter

I deleted WDFF because I don't want numbers to be separated from words. So, query *123ABC456* should match only documents with *123abc456* in it. Only exception I want is with the  hyphen-minus (-) symbol. Query *Wi-Fi* should also match *wifi*.

```
<filter catenateAll="0" 
        catenateNumbers="1"
        catenateWords="1" 
        class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
        generateNumberParts="1" 
        generateWordParts="0"
        preserveOriginal="1" 
        splitOnCaseChange="0"
        splitOnNumerics="1" 
        types="wdfftypes.txt"/>
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the alpahnumeric splitting by setting the following

```
splitOnNumerics="0"
```

Now if you want for `Wi-Fi` to match `WiFi` then use the following property

```
catenateWords=1
```

which I think you are already using.

You can read more about the options here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-WordDelimiterFilter